# Accessing memory cache items

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm writing a Firefox extension and I need to to access items in Firefox's memory cache.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
nsICache = Components.interfaces.nsICache
cacheservice = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/cache-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICacheService);
cachesession = cacheservice.createSession("javascript", nsICache.STORE_IN_MEMORY, false);
cachesession.doomEntriesIfExpired=false;

//fileurl is captured from the nsIObserver and does print out correctly
cachedescriptor = cachesession.openCacheEntry( fileurl, nsICache.ACCESS_READ, false );
ERROR:NS_ERROR_CACHE_KEY_NOT_FOUND here
```

Since this is data fetched in the background, I have to use an nsIObserver to capture the request and snag it's URI to be used as the cache key.

As I showed above, I get a `NS_ERROR_CACHE_KEY` not found, though a look through `about:cache` shows that it clearly is there. I also used a proxy to force caching to disk, but I got the same problem (with the code modified to look at the disk cache). I thought that this might be because the cache item was still being written, so I made a recursive window.setTimeout to continuously call the functions, but even after it is finished downloading I get the same error.

Is this, perhaps, and issue with the `nsICacheSession`? Maybe I'm not use the correct `clientId`. If so, what `clientId` should I be using?

I'm really at a loss here, so I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

Comment: I implemented a cacheVisitor to walk all cache entries, and cacheservice.visitEntries(cacheVisitor) does return the object I am looking for, and the key returned from the cacheVisitor is the exact key I'm using to try to access it with cachesession.openCacheEntry(). This makes me think that there's an error in the way I'm accessing it. However, it all appears to be in order. I mean, I used ( clientId, STORE_IN_MEMORY, false ) and openCacheEntry( fileurl, ACCESS_READ, false )

Comment: I used a cacheVisitor to validate the cache entry. When the proper key is found, it saves it to a global variable. When the cacheVisitor finishes, that saved key is passed to openCacheEntry. Again, I get NS_ERROR_CACHE_KEY_NOT_FOUND. So, again, it's definitely there, but why can't the nsICacheSession locate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the clientId. I used "javascript" because I saw it in an example. Turns out I needed to use "HTTP" instead.